# Fast autocomplete with JavaScript

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI Autocomplete. But it is very slow on typing. When I type for example on Google search box, then the suggestions are ever displayed on the bottom of the box and it is very fast. The autocomplete call for google is taking ca. 80 ms (according to Firebug requests analyse).

My service is delivering the suggestions in the same time range 80-100ms but the implementation of jQuery autocomplete is so slow, that the results are coming under the box after I have written the whole word.

Has someone a better solution for autocomplete in the way like Google's speed or is there any way to optimize the jQuery UI autocomplete?

Comment: Please [don't use signatures or taglines in your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: Post some code, looks like you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From their documentation:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ delay: 300 }); // default
```

Try changing that to:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({ delay: 100 });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works very fine ;-) I have set delay:0 and it is like google ;-)

Comment: Just be careful with setting it to 0. That means every single keystroke will hit your server, which could result in a performance issue down the line.